# Stereographic Sun Diagram matplotlib polar plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I am trying to create a simple stereographic sun path diagram similar to these:
http://wiki.naturalfrequency.com/wiki/Sun-Path_Diagram

I am able to rotate a polar plot and set the scale to 90. How do I go about reversing the y-axis?
Currently the axis goes from 0>90, how do I reverse the axis to 90>0 to represent the azimuth?

I have tried:

```
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.yaxis_inverted()
```

Further, how would I go about creating a stereographic projection as opposed to a equidistant?

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
testFig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8))
rect = [0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8]
testAx = testFig.add_axes(rect,polar=True)
testAx.invert_yaxis()
testAx.set_theta_zero_location('N')
testAx.set_theta_direction(-1)

Azi = [90,180,270]
Alt= [0,42,0]
testAx.plot(Azi,Alt)
plt.show()
```

Currently my code doesn't seem to even plot the lines correctly, do I need need to convert the angle or degrees into something else?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The short answer is that you want a stereographic projection instead of a polar projection.  However, this means that you'll either have to a) subclass the `Axes` yourself (have a look at `projections.geo_axes` in matplotlib, or b) adapt existing code to do what you want. (Just to plug something of my own, mplstereonet: https://github.com/joferkington/mplstereonet can be adapted to this, but it's intended for geologic data.)  I'm busy for the next day or two, but I'll try to post an example of both if someone doesn't beat me to it. :)

Comment: After lots of internet searching, I think that playing around with the y_scale may suffice: [ScaleBase Example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/custom_scale_example.html). Though I am not sure if a reverse scale will work. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @tcaswell hello, please see answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally had time to play around with matplotlib. After much searching, the correct way as Joe Kington points out is to subclass the Axes. I found a much quicker way utilising the excellent basemap module.

Below is some code I have adapted for stackoverflow. The sun altitude and azimuth were calculated with Pysolar with a set of timeseries stamps created in pandas.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

winterAzi = datafomPySolarAzi
winterAlt = datafromPySolarAlt

# create instance of basemap, note we want a south polar projection to 90 = E
myMap = Basemap(projection='spstere',boundinglat=0,lon_0=180,resolution='l',round=True,suppress_ticks=True)
# set the grid up
gridX,gridY = 10.0,15.0
parallelGrid = np.arange(-90.0,90.0,gridX)
meridianGrid = np.arange(-180.0,180.0,gridY)

# draw parallel and meridian grid, not labels are off. We have to manually create these.
myMap.drawparallels(parallelGrid,labels=[False,False,False,False])
myMap.drawmeridians(meridianGrid,labels=[False,False,False,False],labelstyle='+/-',fmt='%i')

# we have to send our values through basemap to convert coordinates, note -winterAlt
winterX,winterY = myMap(winterAzi,-winterAlt)

# plot azimuth labels, with a North label.
ax = plt.gca()
ax.text(0.5,1.025,'N',transform=ax.transAxes,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='bottom',size=25)
for para in np.arange(gridY,360,gridY):
    x= (1.1*0.5*np.sin(np.deg2rad(para)))+0.5
    y= (1.1*0.5*np.cos(np.deg2rad(para)))+0.5
    ax.text(x,y,u'%i\N{DEGREE SIGN}'%para,transform=ax.transAxes,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')


# plot the winter values
myMap.plot(winterX,winterY ,'bo')
```

Note that currently I am only plotting points, you will have to make sure that line points have a point at alt 0 at sunrise/sunset.

[image: stereographic plot, note I have plotted Winter/Summer Solstice and Autumn Equinox]