# How to annotate hours for every point plotted on a sunpath diagram?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap

So below is a code to plot a sunpath diagram. My question is what function would you use to annotate hours for every point plotted on the graph. I have tried both plt.annotate and plt.text from matplotlib, but it doesn't seem to work because the plot is done using basemap.

[Stereographic Sun Diagram matplotlib polar plot python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858806/stereographic-sun-diagram-matplotlib-polar-plot-python/36380361#36380361)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt using the code in the question you linked to and the `annotate` method:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

winterAzi = [90,180,270]
winterAlt = np.array([0,42,0])

# create instance of basemap, note we want a south polar projection to 90 = E
myMap = Basemap(projection='spstere',boundinglat=0,lon_0=180,resolution='l',round=True,suppress_ticks=True)
# set the grid up
gridX,gridY = 10.0,15.0
parallelGrid = np.arange(-90.0,90.0,gridX)
meridianGrid = np.arange(-180.0,180.0,gridY)

# draw parallel and meridian grid, not labels are off. We have to manually create these.
myMap.drawparallels(parallelGrid,labels=[False,False,False,False])
myMap.drawmeridians(meridianGrid,labels=[False,False,False,False],labelstyle='+/-',fmt='%i')

# we have to send our values through basemap to convert coordinates, note -winterAlt
winterX,winterY = myMap(winterAzi,-winterAlt)

# plot azimuth labels, with a North label.
ax = plt.gca()
ax.text(0.5,1.025,'N',transform=ax.transAxes,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='bottom',size=25)
for para in np.arange(gridY,360,gridY):
    x= (1.1*0.5*np.sin(np.deg2rad(para)))+0.5
    y= (1.1*0.5*np.cos(np.deg2rad(para)))+0.5
    ax.text(x,y,u'%i\N{DEGREE SIGN}'%para,transform=ax.transAxes,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')


# plot the winter values
myMap.plot(winterX,winterY ,'bo')

# Annotate points
for x,y,label in zip(winterAlt, winterAzi, ["point 1","point 2","point 3"]):
    plt.annotate(label, xy=myMap(y, -x), xycoords="data", xytext=(5, 5), 
                 textcoords='offset points',ha="left",va="center",fontsize=12)
```

The loop at the end loops over the x/y coordinates and labels for each of the points, and uses `annotate` to add the labels at the specified coordinates (with the offset given in `xytext`)

Output:

### Heading

[image: output]